# Merge the tags "game" and "games" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [games](/questions/tagged/games) tag has 169 questions and the [game](/questions/tagged/game) has 113.

Not sure which should be merged into which. It seems like the singular [game](/questions/tagged/game) makes sense most of the time (for example, a question is likely about "iPhone game crashing", rather than "iPhone games crashing"), but obviously [games](/questions/tagged/games) is more commonly used.

Comment: There is only one question that has both tags.

Comment: Related tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~game~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged [games] and a few others with 1 or 2 questions into [game]; am happy to go either [games] or [game], but *in the context*, the singular seemed to make more sense. It also scanned for any obvious unrelated questions, but couldn't see any (note that [games] and [game] are very far apart in meaning).

I haven't touched [game-development] at the moment; see comment.

Answer (score 4):

A (very) casual glance at the lists doesn't show much in the way of consistency; I second the merge proposal and recommend the singular.

Answer (score 4):

I think 'games' is a category that covers many things, so the plural is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) tag (640 questions). Is this used in the same way as `game` and `games`? A quick look-through suggests all three are interchangeable.

If they are equivalent, then perhaps `game-development` should be the one to live on. It's the most popular, most specific and is unambiguous.

Comment: But then, why not C#-development, python-development...

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Good point about the name. Let's wait for more feedback from others (preferably from people that use these tags).

Comment: Because C# allready has as strong correlation to developtment, while game doesn't

Comment: But the *site* does, and we tend to close non-programming game questions.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, "game" could be a verb like "hack" or "kluge".

"Games" will almost always be a plural noun.

I don't think the tags should be merged.

Comment: Whatever you think the tags COULD be used for is entirely different than what they are probably being used for right now.

Comment: There shouldn't be any questions aboug gaming, so "game" would be invalid on SO.